# Is there a way to save this tablet from bootloop?

Tags: recovery-mode, boot-loop, boot

I have several generic tablets running Jelly Bean 4.2.2. Recently one of them started bootlooping out of the blue. Unfortunately, the tablets have proprietary, stripped versions of android and recovery. There are no options to data reset in recovery and adb recovery --wipe_data or adb --wipe_data do not work. The tablet in loop can be accessed by adb but services such as activity manager or package manager are not running. Following is the top of logcat for both an operating tablet as well as the looper.

Bootlooper

```
--------- beginning of /dev/log/system
I/RegionTag(  106): ----------------running drmservice---------------
I/RegionTag(  106): ----------serianno =X2QU82WEPG
I/RegionTag(  106): auto generate serialno,serialno = X2QU82WEPG
I/RegionTag(  106): detect keybox enabled
I/Vold    (   97): Vold 2.1 (the revenge) firing up
D/Vold    (   97): Volume flash state changing -1 (Initializing) -> 0 (No-Media)
E/Vold    (   97): ---------get mtd_name is user---
E/Vold    (   97): ------------find mtd name is user, num is 9----
E/Vold    (   97): ---------get mtd_name is user---
E/Vold    (   97): ------------find mtd name is user, num is 9----
I/Vold    (   97): Call notifyStateKernel No.1 in the file of VOlume.cpp
D/Vold    (   97): Volume sdcard state changing -1 (Initializing) -> 0 (No-Media)
D/Vold    (   97): Volume udisk state changing -1 (Initializing) -> 0 (No-Media)
E/Vold    (   97): Start Misc devices Manager...
D/Vold    (   97): Volume flash state changing 0 (No-Media) -> 1 (Idle-Unmounted)
I/SystemServer(  360): Entered the Android system server!
I/SystemServer(  360): Enabled StrictMode logging for UI Looper
I/SystemServer(  360): Waiting for installd to be ready.
I/SystemServer(  360): Enabled StrictMode logging for WM Looper
I/Installer(  360): connecting...
I/SystemServer(  360): Entropy Mixer
I/SystemServer(  360): Power Manager
I/SystemServer(  360): Activity Manager
I/ActivityManager(  360): Memory class: 64
I/UsageStats(  360): Deleting usage file : usage-20110101
--------- beginning of /dev/log/main
D/dalvikvm(  360): GC_CONCURRENT freed 404K, 11% free 4277K/4776K, paused 2ms+2ms, total 12ms
D/dalvikvm(  360): GC_CONCURRENT freed 404K, 11% free 4277K/4776K, paused 1ms+1ms, total 9ms
D/dalvikvm(  360): GC_CONCURRENT freed 404K, 11% free 4277K/4776K, paused 2ms+2ms, total 12ms
D/dalvikvm(  360): GC_CONCURRENT freed 404K, 11% free 4277K/4776K, paused 2ms+2ms, total 12ms
D/dalvikvm(  360): GC_CONCURRENT freed 404K, 11% free 4277K/4776K, paused 2ms+2ms, total 12ms
D/dalvikvm(  360): GC_CONCURRENT freed 404K, 11% free 4277K/4776K, paused 2ms+2ms, total 11ms
D/dalvikvm(  360): GC_CONCURRENT freed 404K, 11% free 4277K/4776K, paused 2ms+2ms, total 12ms
```

---

```
Working tablet
--------- beginning of /dev/log/system
I/RegionTag(  106): ----------------running drmservice---------------
I/RegionTag(  106): ----------serianno =J1VQXV9RYH
I/RegionTag(  106): auto generate serialno,serialno = J1VQXV9RYH
I/RegionTag(  106): detect keybox enabled
I/Vold    (   96): Vold 2.1 (the revenge) firing up
D/Vold    (   96): Volume flash state changing -1 (Initializing) -> 0 (No-Media)
E/Vold    (   96): ---------get mtd_name is user---
E/Vold    (   96): ------------find mtd name is user, num is 9----
E/Vold    (   96): ---------get mtd_name is user---
E/Vold    (   96): ------------find mtd name is user, num is 9----
I/Vold    (   96): Call notifyStateKernel No.1 in the file of VOlume.cpp
D/Vold    (   96): Volume sdcard state changing -1 (Initializing) -> 0 (No-Media)
D/Vold    (   96): Volume udisk state changing -1 (Initializing) -> 0 (No-Media)
E/Vold    (   96): Start Misc devices Manager...
D/Vold    (   96): Volume flash state changing 0 (No-Media) -> 1 (Idle-Unmounted)
I/SystemServer(  370): Entered the Android system server!
I/SystemServer(  370): Waiting for installd to be ready.
I/SystemServer(  370): Enabled StrictMode logging for UI Looper
I/SystemServer(  370): Enabled StrictMode logging for WM Looper
I/Installer(  370): connecting...
I/SystemServer(  370): Entropy Mixer
I/SystemServer(  370): Power Manager
I/SystemServer(  370): Activity Manager
I/ActivityManager(  370): Memory class: 64
I/SystemServer(  370): Display Manager
I/ActivityManager(  370): Enabled StrictMode logging for AThread's Looper
I/SystemServer(  370): Telephony Registry
I/SystemServer(  370): Scheduling Policy
I/DisplayManagerService(  370): Display device added: DisplayDeviceInfo{"Built-in Screen": 600 x 1024, 57.727 fps, density 160, 177.2093 x 168.89351 dpi, touch INTERNAL, FLAG_DEFAULT_DISPLAY, FLAG_ROTATES_WITH_CONTENT, FLAG_SECURE, FLAG_SUPPORTS_PROTECTED_BUFFERS, rotation 0, type BUILT_IN, address null}
I/SystemServer(  370): Package Manager
I/PackageManager(  370): Need to read from backup settings file
W/PackageManager(  370): Cleaning up settings file /data/system/packages.xml
```

Comment: what about fastboot mode? is bootloader locked?

Comment: reboot bootloader = black screen no input reboot recovery = one option press power to reboot but you can use adb

Comment: adb in recovery? you can `cat /proc/partitions` and format biggest one (should be userdata) `mke2fs -t ext4 /dev/block/mmcblk0p99`

Comment: Unfortunately, the tablet does not have root access only shell, the native mke2fs is in sbin directory and access to it can only be done by root. So, I tried moving a copy of the binary to /data/local/tmp and running it from there but I get what I expect is the same problem with using wipe, that being, no permissions for the /data partition. Anyway this was the actual error when I tried: 
shell@android:/data/local/tmp $ ./mke2fs -t ext4 /dev/block/mtdblock6
mke2fs 1.41.14 (22-Dec-2010)
mke2fs: Permission denied while trying to determine filesystem size